# Meaning of "they were alone"

Tags: meaning

I am wondering if the meaning of "they were alone" can be interpreted in two different ways.

One, they, the people, were alone in a place like a room, but as a group, meaning they were in the same place, but no one beside them were there/

Two, they, the people, were alone individually in different rooms, meaning they were all in a room of their own, each had a room and they were the only person occupying their respective rooms.

Comment: Yes, those are both totally valid understandings. Permit me to suggest a third, which is rather unhappy, but I have used it and heard it. `They were alone` might even be aimed at emphasizing that there is a sort of aloneness, an isolation, that remains even though they are in the same room and very near each other. This is perhaps more poetic, but it is a real usage.

Comment: I would say the first interpretation is much more common, especially in romantic literature.

Comment: It might also mean that they had something in common as a group (such as agreement on something), that set them apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both interpretations are valid, but interpretation one is much more common (probably because the situation itself happens more often). You can add the word *together* to emphasize it, e.g. in the following example sentences from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/alone):

> - There were a lot of opportunities for them to be alone together discussing her graduation project.
> - That winter the two writers were alone together for the first time, but it was not an idyllic experience.

For situation two, I'd be inclined to add *separately* and use *isolated* instead of *alone*:

> They were isolated separately.

but it could also be clear from the context, e.g.

> They were alone, each in their own room.

As others noted in the comments, it's also possible to interpret the sentence in a more figurative way.